# Efficiently determining if a discrete log exists

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Finding a discrete log in a finite cyclic group, like $(Z_N)^x$, seems hard and in some cases a solution may not even exist. Consider $N=15$ and the generator function $2^k=m \bmod 15$. This will produce the following values for $m$ given any non negative integer $k$...

$1, 2, 4, 8, 1, \dots$

Therefor, the equation $2^k=3 \bmod 15$ would have no (real?) solution. Is there a "fast" way of determining if any solution exists without factoring N?

Comment: If memory serves, computing the discrete logarithm is about as hard as factoring itself...

Comment: @J.M. That is correct but I'm asking about determining *if* a solution exists, not what the solution is. This seems like a subtle but important difference.

Comment: [Nitpicking.] In a cyclic group the discrete logarithm always exists (unless you picked a wrong base for the log). In $\mathbf{Z}_N^*$ it may not always exist, because the group in question is not always cyclic. [/Nitpicking] A good question! But how does factoring $N$ help us decide the answer? You seem to be implying that it would?

Comment: I'm convinced that the existence problem for discrete logs is as hard as the problem of finding discrete logs, but I'm not having much luck finding support for my conviction.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen if you wish to edit the question to be more exact in terminology, I wouldn't complain. As to the factoring of N, I may be wrong, but for some reason I thought that would help; however I seem to be having issues proving that now.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's what I thought as well but I also couldn't find any references or proves that say otherwise. Which is why I posted the question.

Comment: Closest thing I've found is a paper by Kevin McCurley at http://www.mccurley.org/papers/dlog.pdf which says, "An alternative way to state the [discrete logarithm] problem is, Given $a,g$ in $G$, determine if there exists an integer $x$ such that $g^x=a$, and if so, find such an $x$. Note that this formulation of the problem might be harder to solve."

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1301314/163

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of a fast way to solve the decision version of discrete log but given the problem of deciding if a solution to $a^x=b \bmod n$ exists for known $a$,$b$ the following steps will often show that a solution does not exist:

(1) Factor the modulus into prime powers. By the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) a solution exists if it exists mod each prime power
(2) For each of these factor $p$-1
(3) Compute the order of $a$ and $b$ mod $p^k$ using the factorization of $p$-1 (can be done quickly using a generalization of Euler's criterion)
(4) A solution does not exist if the order of $b$ does not divide the order of $a$.

Misc remarks:
(1) It is unknown if factoring $n$ reduces to being able to solve the decision discrete log mod $n$.
(2) Its not hard to show factoring $n$ reduces to the computational version of discrete log mod $n$ (discrete log can be used to compute the order of any element mod $n$ and there is a well known way to factor $n$ given this. It's described on [the Wikipedia page for Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor's_algorithm)).
(3) Given the factors of $n$, discrete log mod $n$ reduces to discrete log mod $p$. It is unknown if a fast method for factoring any number would imply that the discrete log mod primes can also be solved quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Chinese Remainder Theorem applies here. Note that $2^k = 7$ has no solution mod $15$, but has solutions mod $3$ and $5$.